# Mood/Emotion Detection (Happy to Sad) using OpenCV

Tags: animation, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, face-detection

My project is to detect the mood of a person in an image.
I want it as  a percentage from 0-100; 0 for very sad and 100 for very happy.

**Can I do it using OpenCV?**

Should I download any database for my project for training purpose? If so please help me to start?

**Edit:**

I have come across this [link](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/tutorial/facerec_gender_classification.html) in OpenCV tutorials. The example is for Gender but the link mentions we can do the same for Emotion also.

Can anyone provide me any reference or suggestions on what DB to download the database and how to do cropping (only lips or ...). How many images?

Comment: close vote? you can suggest me the reason so that I can improve my question. Please..

Comment: Any progress on this? Have you succeeded?

Answer (score 3):

There is a coding system for facial muscles known as [Action Units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facial_Action_Coding_System) which codifies a facial expression according to the presence or absence of 46 different action descriptors. The list of these descriptors can be found on the linked page and can be used to recognize emotion from a given face.

If you collect a set of facial images for which you both assign a happiness or sadness score and additionally label the presence and absence of the action descriptors you can obtain a simple data set which will allow you to train a classifier (such as Naive Bayes or Semi-Naive Bayes) to recognize an emotion score from faces.

Of course, this will require your input images to additionally be pre-labeled with Action Units. This could could potentially be achieved with a different learning system, perhaps based on the [OpenCV boosted classifier cascade](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html).